# Incorrectly reading lines of a text File in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

So basically i want to iterate the lines of a text file that has this format:

```
-----------------------------------------
Code: 0123456789
EGGS: 3 7.00 21.00
BACON: 1 3.50 3.50
COFFEE: 2 14.20 28.40
TOTAL: 52.90
-----------------------------------------
```

and i have the following code to read the lines one by one:

```
with open(filename, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
   for line in f:
       prevline = line
       line.split()

       if '-' in line:
           temp = f.readline().split(':') #Get Code
           print(temp)
           AFM = temp[1]
           print(AFM)
       else:
           tempProducts = line.split(':') #Get Product in a list 
           productName = tempProducts[0] #Store Product Name in a variable
           productStats = tempProducts[1] #Store Product Stats in a list
           productStats = productStats.split(" ")
           for value in productStats:
               valueArray.append(float(value))
               products.update({productName:valueArray})
       if '-' in f.readline():
           rec = Receipt(AFM,products)
           products={}
           valueArray=[]
           receipts.append(rec)
       else:
           line=prevline
```

mind that i want to skip the line with the '------------' characters the code works but it keeps reading second line then fourth then sixth(code,bacon,total). The question is how can i fix this.Edit: there are multiple receipts in the file so i need each time to skip the line with the'----------'.

Comment: What is the expected output, it's not really clear to me. What is `Receipt`?

Comment: the expected output is that i have a(eg Bacon) valueArray=['1','3.50','3.50'] and a products{Bacon:valueArray} Bacon=key and valueArray=value in a dictionary and do this for all the lines except for the line with Code.And Create an Object with that information and put it in a list

Comment: Is the `AFM` always following `Code:`?

Comment: Yes the AFM always stores the Code

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    old_list = [] # Saving all the lines including '----' 
       for line in f:
           old_list.append(line)
    new_list = old_list[1:-1] # new list which removes the '----' lines
```

You can iterate just through new_list with your .split logic.

Comment: the problem with this is that are multiple receipts in a file sorry i didnt clarify that.Im new to Stack Overflow

Comment: Could you please provide the expected JSON/dict output here, considering multiple receipts in the file.

Comment: i mean the code stores the information correctly but instead of reading the lines one by one it reads them two by two meaning it skips one line.It goes code->bacon->total but i want to go code->eggs->bacon->coffee->total and read its values

Answer (score 0):

See if this does the job

```
with open(filename, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    valueArray = []
    for line in f:
        if not '-' in line:
            if 'Code' in line:
                AFM = line.split(':')[1]
                print(AFM)
                valueArray = []
                products = {}
            else:
                tempProducts = line.split(':')  # Get Product in a list
                productName = tempProducts[0]  # Store Product Name in a variable
                productStats = tempProducts[1]  # Store Product Stats in a list
                productStats_list = productStats.split(" ")
                for value in productStats:
                    valueArray.append(float(value))
                products.update({productName: valueArray})
                if 'TOTAL' in line:
                    rec = Receipt(AFM, products)
                    receipts.append(rec)
```

Comment: no sry i mean the code stores the information correctly but instead of reading the lines one by one it reads them two by two meaning it skips one line.It goes from code->bacon->total but i want to go code->eggs->bacon->coffee->total

Comment: You already iterate through your file with `for line in f` so you should not have any other `f.readline` in your code block. Further there are statements that don't make sense to me, what is `prevline` used for? And I know Python allows this, but I recommend to create new objects for new datatypes instead of wildly re-use them (e.g. `productStats`), `line.split()` doesn't do anything

Comment: My output {'Bacon': ['1', '3.50', '3.50\n'], 'Total': ['52.90\n']} but i need a dict with all lines(Bacon,coffee,total,eggs)

Comment: It's not that I'm not willing to help, you just need to provide more information

Answer (score 0):

To anyone seeing this post now consider it closed i do not provide enough information and the code was messed up. Sorry for wasting your time